# how to restrict the direct url file name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to restrict direct URL file name in javascript!when I entered the HTML files direct URL  it should not allow showing contents inside. it should alert message to the user. it has to work only when we are clicking index file link.

Files are 1.index.html
          2.viewer.html

I tried to restrict direct access in viewer.html but it is not working. the viewer page should display it's content when I was clicking the link in the index.html page.

**Viewer.html code**

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http:files/tutorial.pdf&chrome=true" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">

var accepted_domains=new Array("viewer.html","viewer.html")

var domaincheck=document.location.href //retrieve the current URL of user browser
var accepted_ok=false //set acess to false by default

if (domaincheck.indexOf("http")!=-1){ //if this is a http request
    for (r=0;r<accepted_domains.length;r++){
        if (domaincheck.indexOf(accepted_domains[r])!=-1){ //if a match is found
            accepted_ok=true //set access to true, and break out of loop
            break
        }
    }
}
else
    accepted_ok=true

if (!accepted_ok){
    alert("You\'re not allowed to directly link to this file on our server!")
    history.back(-1)
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is called "preventing hotlinking", and typically done on server side. For how to do it with a .htaccess file (on Apache), Google e.g. `htaccess prevent hotlinking`

Comment: without from server side, i've to do within local using HTML and javascript whether its possible or not

Comment: I'm not *quite* sure what you are trying to do in your code. You want to show things in `viewer.html` only if the visitor came from `index.html`, correct?

Comment: yeah exactly! but I have to  use only HTML and javascript to achieve

Comment: Yes, it seems to be possible, by checking `document.referer` - the URL the user came from will be in there.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use "document.referrer" property.

If it is your entry point, then document.referrer will be set to "".

If you link to child page, then your document referrer will be set to your host/entry.html

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

not as good as server side, but something.

Answer (score 0):

**test 1.html:**

`<a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>`

**test2.html:**

```
<script>
    if (document.referrer.indexOf('localhost:81/test1.html') == -1) window.location = 'test1.html'
</script>
```

This also allows you to specify a hostname, not just a filename.  (leave protocol off to make it protocol-agnostic)

Disclaimer: For REAL security, this lockout should be done server-side.